# socket.io connection refused with node.js

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

In the HTML I have this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.2/socket.io.js"></script>
```

And:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://www.myurl.com:8000');
```

If I run it, I get the error "Connection Refused".
I currently have this index.js:

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});


server.listen(8000);
```

[network tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q6CT.png)

Comment: versions should be the same, using v1.0.0 client to connect to v3.1.2 won't work

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice! I have updating the version but the error remains :(

Comment: can you show a screen of the network tab?

Comment: yes sure, it is uploaded

Comment: check @ChristianFritz's answer first

Comment: I did but it did not fix the error

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

needs to be

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

see https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-initialization/#With-Express.

Comment: hey thank you, it seems not to fix the issue :/

Comment: it works for me. Are you sure your domain and all is correctly configured? Can you retrieve the page fine in the browser?